# Trouble using Windows forms to design GUI

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, drawing, system.drawing

I'm trying to write a simple GUI that renders a number of images using the Graphics' object primitives. What I want to have is a series of areas that I can paint to in isolation of the other areas, so that each painting "canvas" has it's own origin within the global coordinate frame of the top-level form.

So far I have tried adding several panels to a FlowLayoutPanel. However, they seem to be getting placed one on top of the other, as only one onPaint method is being called. I can override the Form's onPaint to invalidate the other panels, which are then painted, but not displayed.

Besides setting the sizes, and initialising the FlowLayoutPanel, is there something I'm missing? Is there a better way of doing this?

Code: http://pastebin.com/30Uf9AGF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the names of your classes, it looks like you are designing a game ... maybe you want to take a look at Microsofts XNA framework?

however, the problem with the code you provided is, your layoutPanel is not sized correctly, therefore its child-controls are not visible on the main form... since painting is only done for visible items ... there is no painting for most of your FloorDrawPanels ...

try changing the size of your layoutPanel or setting its dock mode to fill

Comment: NOt writing a game, a visualisation for a new machine learning algorithm for decentralised reinfocement learning. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't set the size of the FlowLayoutPanel.  It will default to 200 x 100 with a Margin of 3.  You fill it with controls that are 100 x 100.  Given the margin, only one of those controls can ever be visible at the same time.  It is therefore no surprise that you only ever get one paint event, Windows only asks visible controls to paint themselves.

Not quite sure what was intended, start by making the FLP bigger.  And set its AutoScroll property to true so that the user can scroll the other controls into view.  Using the designer would have been a quick way to find this out btw.

Comment: Thanks. I have added AutoScroll, but have used DarkSquirrel's dock mode to set the size. Using the designer isn't an option; I'm developing this using monodevelop on Linux.